# traverse backwards in a string using python string.find() function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string

```
mystr = "My mail id is abcd1234@account.com and xzy1234@mailinglist.com"
index = mymail.find('@') #gives me index using which i can traverse further with the mail id
```

How to get only word before @ (i.e abcd1234 and xzy1234) and word after @ (i.e account.com and mailinglist.com) without using list and only using find.

for ex:

```
index = mymail.find('@')
res = mymail.find(' ',index)
mystr[index+1:res] gives me --> account.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` function like below,

```
>>> s = 'My mail id is abcd1234@account.com and xzy1234@mailinglist.com'
```

To get the word before `@`,

```
>>> re.findall(r'\S+(?=@)', s)
['abcd1234', 'xzy1234']
```

To get the word after `@`,

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=@)\S+', s)
['account.com', 'mailinglist.com']
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `(?=@)` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by an `@` symbol. `(?<=@)` Positive lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by an `@` symbol.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, but is there any other way to answer this without re?? only using find?? i was just checking for the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly:

```
S.rfind(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
```

rfind looks for the "last" space in the string not the first one.